# How to compare 2 strings with int out of errors?

Tags: c#, string, diff

I've searched online for a diff algorithm but none of them do what I am looking for. It is for a texting contest (as in cell phone) and I need the entry text compared to the master text recording the errors along the way. I am semi-new to C# and I get most of the string functions and didn't think this was going to be that hard of a problem, but alas I just can't wrap my head around it.

I have a form with 2 rich-text-boxes (one on top of the other) and 2 buttons. The top box is the master text (string) and the bottom box is the entry text (string). Every contestant is sending a text to an email account, from the email we copy and paste the text into the Entry RTB and compare to the Master RTB. For each single word and single space counts as a thing to check. A word, no matter how many errors it has, is still 1 error. And for every error add 1 sec. to their time.

**Examples:**

- Hello there! <= 3 checks (2 words and 1 space)

  - Helothere! <= 2 errors (Helo and space)
  - Hello there!! <= 1 error (extra ! at end of there!)
- Hello there! How are you? <= 9 checks (5 words and 4 spaces)

  - Helothere!! How a re you? <= still 9 checks, 4 errors(helo, no space, extra !, and a space in are)
  - Hello there!@ Ho are yu?? <= 3 errors (@ at end of there!, no w, no o and extra ? (all errors are still under the 1 word)

What I have so far:
I've created 6 arrays (3 for master, 3 for entry) and they are

- CharArray of all chars
- StringArray of all strings(words) including the *spaces*
- IntArray with length of the string in each StringArray

My biggest trouble is if the entry text is wrong and it's shorter or longer than the master. I keep getting IndexOutOfRange exceptions (understandably) but can't fathom how to go about checking and writing the code to compensate.
I hope I have made myself clear enough as to what I need help with. If anyone could give some code examples or something to shoot me in the right path would be very helpful.

Comment: won't the length difference give you the error difference in 'int' !

Comment: Yes. But that wouldn't add the errors i need would it?

Comment: Why 2 errors for Helo and Space? Shouldn't the errors be for space and there! or 3 errors? And are you sure you won't have a (first string)Hello there! (second string)there!

Comment: @ xanatos: This is a _texting contest_ like as in cell phone texting. The rules are 1 error for single or whole word wrong and 1 error for a _space_. So in that example "Helo" is misspelled and the _space_ isn't there. The word "there!" is intact and not mistyped so it would be correct. And the examples are not code output, they are what could be texted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm?  It returns the number of differences between two strings, which, in your case would be texting errors.  Implementing the algorithm based off the pseudo-code found on the wikipedia page passes the first 3 of your 4 use cases:

```
Assert.AreEqual(2, LevenshteinDistance("Hello there!", "Helothere!");
Assert.AreEqual(1, LevenshteinDistance("Hello there!", "Hello there!!"));

Assert.AreEqual(4, LevenshteinDistance("Hello there! How are you?", "Helothere!! How a re you?"));
Assert.AreEqual(3, LevenshteinDistance("Hello there! How are you?", "Hello there!@ Ho are yu??"));  //fails, returns 4 errors
```

So while not perfect out of the box, it is probably a good starting point for you.  Also, if you have too much trouble implementing your scoring rules, it might be worth revisiting them.

hth

### Update:

Here is the result of the string you requested in the comments:

```
Assert.AreEqual(7, LevenshteinDistance("Hello there! How are you?", "Hlothere!! Hw a reYou?");  //fails, returns 8 errors
```

And here is my implementation of the Levenshtein Distance algorithm:

```
int LevenshteinDistance(string left, string right)
{
    if (left == null || right == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (left.Length == 0)
    {
        return right.Length;
    }

    if (right.Length == 0)
    {
        return left.Length;
    }

    int[,] distance = new int[left.Length + 1, right.Length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= left.Length; i++)
    {
        distance[i, 0] = i;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= right.Length; j++)
    {
        distance[0, j] = j;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= left.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= right.Length; j++)
        {
            if (right[j - 1] == left[i - 1])
            {
                distance[i, j] = distance[i - 1, j - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                distance[i, j] = Min(distance[i - 1, j] + 1,      //deletion
                                     distance[i, j - 1] + 1,      //insertion
                                     distance[i - 1, j - 1] + 1); //substitution
            }
        }
    }

    return distance[left.Length, right.Length];
}

int Min(int val1, int val2, int val3)
{
    return Math.Min(val1, Math.Min(val2, val3));
}
```

Comment: @ tdaines: I have looked into Levenshtein distance and it seemed close to what I was trying to do. Why did it return 4 on the last one?? I'm assuming because of the o and the extra ? in the same word.

Comment: @ tdaines: If you still have that code up can you try another compare?

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm would be to check letter by letter.  If the letters differ increment the num of errors.  If the next pairing of letters match, its a switched letter so just continue.  If the messup matches the next letter, it is an omission and treat it accordingly.  If the next letter matches the messed up one, its an insertion and treat it accordingly.  Else the person really messed up and continue.

This doesn't get everything but with a few modifications this could become comprehensive.

a weak attempt at pseudocode:
edit: new idea. look at comments.  I don't know the string functions off the top of my head so you'll have to figure that part out.  The algorithm kinda fails for words that repeat a lot though...

```
string entry; //we'll pretend that this has stuff inside
string master; // this too...
string tempentry = entry; //stuff will be deleted so I need a copy to mess up
int e =0; //word index for entry
int m = 0; //word index for master
int errors = 0;
while(there are words in tempentry) //!tempentry.empty() ?
  string mword = the next word in master;
  m++;
  int eplace = find mword in tempentry; //eplace is the index of where the mword starts in tempentry
  if(eplace == -1) //word not there...
    continue;
  else
     errors += m - e;
     errors += find number of spaces before eplace
     e = m // there is an error
     tempentry = stripoff everything between the beginning and the next word// substring?
all words and spaces left in master are considered errors.
```

There are a couple of bounds checking errors that need to be fixed here but its a good start.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't think you thought it all the way through like I had when I started. I've thought of doing it this way many times but then you have to look at the different errors possible. M(Hello there! How are you?)(25c:9s) - E(Hellohere!! How a re you?)(25c:9s). Stats are the same but with each error the strings indexes start shifting out of place with the master. Errors are: _space_ between _Hello_ and _there!_, extra !, are with a _space_in it. So this would be 3 errors total. Still very puzzling to me.

Comment: isn't that 4 errors? No space, no t, extra !, and extra space.  Or are you treating words as the smallest unit and checking if words are wrong?

Comment: @ datdo: Yes i guess. 1 word with 1 or more errors is still 1 error. Each word and each space will at most equal 1 error.

Comment: ok so this problem simplifies to determining the beginning and endings of words.  I'll see what I can come up with though I'm pretty sure this is an NP-complete problem.  You're probably going to have to try every possible combination  to get it exactly correct every time.

Comment: @datdo: NP? And I am afraid that this will be way more taxing on me than I thought it would have been. I just cant believe that this hasn't been done before at least something close to. I mean they have typing programs that show errors in colors and you can change options for error level control. That's why I figured it would be easier. The program is simple until you through in the ' '. That's when it takes the hard-ball express.

Comment: @KaktusJack I think I got it.  Iterate through the list of words in master and check to see if they are in the entry.  If it isn't look for the next word in master that appears. The difference between the two is the number of wrong letter words in between.  You can then just count spaces to figure out wrong space words.  I'll try edit my code above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to come up with a scoring systems that works for you're situation.

I would make a word array after each space.

- If a word is found on the same index +5.
- If a word is found on the same index +-1 index location +3 (keep a counter how much words differ to increase the +- correction
- If a needed word is found as part of another word +2

etc.etc. Matching words is hard, getting up with a rules engine that works is 'easier'

Comment: but I wanted to keep this simple as possible. It's all based off time and accuracy. The accuracy is what the program is checking (hopefully) the time is based off of how long it took them to text the message and how many errors (added to sec. as penalty). 1 word(no matter how many mistakes) is 1 sec. and 1 space missing is 1 sec. I have 3 arrays for each string. CharArray for all chrs, StringArray for every word + spaces, and IntArray for the length of each string in the StringArray. My problem is I don't know how about coding this to compensate erros and the IndexOutOfRange Exception.

Comment: Its not a simple problem. So there is no simple solution. You've just added a lot of information about scoring. Get someone to write some good scoring code if you can't do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented an algorithm (which I can't find at the moment, I'll post code when I find it) which looked at the total number of PAIRS in the target string. i.e. "Hello, World!" would have 11 pairs, { "He", "el", "ll",...,"ld", "d!" }.

You then do the same thing on an input string such as "Helo World" so you have { "He",...,"ld" }.

You can then calculate accuracy as a function of correct pairs (i.e. input pairs that are in the list of target pairs), incorrect pairs (i.e. input pairs that do not exists in the list of target pairs), compared to the total list of target pairs. Over long enough sentences, this measure would be very <strike>accurate</strike> fair.